# Get time zone identifier from an ISO string

Tags: javascript

I receive an iso string with time zone like this: `2021-07-08T11:22:33+0200`.

How can I get the time zone identifier (like `Europe/Stockholm`) from that string?

Note that I don't need my local or browser's time zone, but that one from the received date "+0200".

Comment: You can't, there's not enough info. There may be more than 1 timezone with that offset (+02:00) and no way to know which one it is. You may get lucky and find only 1 for an offset but they are few and far between (if they exist at all).

Comment: It's not possible to find it unless identifier is in the string. There are many places in same time zone. You can never know

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10087819/convert-date-to-another-timezone-in-javascript

Comment: There are only a few unique time zones, such as Kathmandu, Chatham Island, Lord Howe Island, Eucla.  Do you have any other geolocation data to use, such as IP address?

Comment: No. I think @phuzi and others were right. It can't be done only with that date string.